# How to design inductor for non-isolated boost converter?

Tags: inductor, design, boost, converter

I am trying to design an inductor of 500uH for non-isolated boost converter from following data.
Input voltage Vin=330V DC,
Maximum duty ratio Dmax=63%,
Switching frequency Fsw=30kHz,
Saturation flux density=0.4 T,
Maximum flux density Bmax=0.2 T,
Peak current Ipeak=70 A,
RMS current Irms=50 A,
Current density J=5A/mm^2,
Min conductor area required Acond=Irms/J=10 mm^2.

I have selected 4 stacks of  EE80/38/20 core (N27 material), 
So Core area Ae= 1552 mm^2,
Window area Aw=1080 mm^2.

1.
I know

L=N*Bmax*Ae/Ipeak,

N(turns)=L*Ipeak/(Bmax*Ae).

I am getting approximately 112 turns.

So total bare conductor area=N*Acond=112*10=1120 mm^2

Excluding Window area utilization factor (Kw)

So winding is going out of a window.

2.
I know one more relation of calculating the minimum number of turns.

N=1000*SQRT(L/AL)

If I consider AL=0.5 mH/turn  (Am I considering this wrong?)

then, N=1000*SQRT(500u/0.5) =32 turns

And now required bare conductor area =N*Acond=32*10=320 mm^2

By including Kw and increasing awg of winding it can fit into a core.

I am not getting where I am going wrong here?

link to Datasheet of core is [Datasheet of core](https://en.tdk.eu/inf/80/db/fer/e_80_38_20.pdf)

Comment: Is this a fixed frequency? If so, what's f? Do you know the duty cycle? Can you talk a little more about the input and output voltages?

Comment: I will make changes  in my question

Comment: So, is your average output current 13 A and the output about 900 V? Are we talking about 10 kW?

Comment: Just off the cuff, I get that your magnetic volume, \$l_e\cdot A_c\$ must be at least \$220\times 10^{-9}\cdot \mu_e\$.

Comment: You should consider what I said as a comment in your previous question. You won't get 100% help by disrespecting those that help you. It's give and take in life.

Comment: Yes, actually power is approx 16Kw. Vout=750 and Iout=22. I didn't understand le*Ae product logic. Can I get a link to understand it?                                                       
those calculations in question are right or wrong?

Comment: @vck No, I've got no link. Books perhaps. Some of what I know came from taking a Unitrode class. But here I just used some notes I've kept where I developed these equations from the work of others. I used your figures for D=.63 and your peak current expectation and your input voltage, as given. (Also, that's in \$m^3\$.)